# Входит ли дата во временной интервал?

Tags: php

Имеется дата 2019-07-01 16:22:01

как проверить, входит ли эта дата между 17:40 и 23:59?

Comment: Нужно понимать что в формате «дата время» есть два значения, в вопрошаемом периоде - только время. И как вы будете проверять на вхождение?

Answer (score 1):

Вот как-то так:

```
$var1 = strtotime('2019-07-01 17:40');
$var2 = strtotime('2019-07-01 16:22:01');
$var3 = strtotime('2019-07-01 23:59');

if($var1 < $var2 and $var2 < $var3){
  echo 'Вы попали)';
}else{
  echo 'Вы не попали)';
}
```

Причем даты могут быть разные! Если `$var2` будет больше чем `$var1` и меньше чем `$var3` то время в нужном диапазоне.

**Примечание** формат времени во всех переменных должен совпадать. То-есть если в переменной 1 указано только время, то и в остальных должно быть указано только время. Если даты, то во всех должны быть только даты. Их вариация не имеет значения.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$a = strtotime ('2019-07-01 16:22:00');
$b = strtotime ('2019-07-01 16:22:01');
$c = strtotime ('2019-07-01 16:22:02');

var_dump ($b > $a and $b < $c);

// bool(true)
```